# I'm migrating a high traffic service to Kubernetes. What logging solutions should I be looking into?

Tags: logging, kubernetes

I'm in the middle of migrating an existing service to Kubernetes on Linode.

I'm researching some different logging and reporting options now that are more comprehensive than what I've been doing for the last few years and could use some advice.

For quite a while I've been using a combination of the basic logging provided by Linode for my VM's (in/out bandwidth, cpu, mem graphs) and a local Grafana/Ingressdb installation to collect some basic info about clients connecting to the service (mainly for knowing requests per second over different time periods).

I know Traefik has some built-in visual displays, but I ended up going with Kubernete's nginx ingress controller as it was somewhat easier to configure at this stage.

I'd love to get some feedback on:

- Considerations I should have for properly monitoring and getting
  alerting around the new k8s cluster.
- Recommendations for different products (OSS or commercial) related to comprehensive logging and reporting.
- Things I don't know that I should know.

Thanks!

Comment: Product recommendations are [off topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm researching some different logging and reporting options now that are more comprehensive than what I've been doing for the last few years and could use some advice.

As far as I can see, you are doing a research now; unfortunately, there is no info on which exactly logging you have at the moment, that is why it's hard to provide *precise* answer (if possible at all, because everyone run their own apps, loads, etc).

However, quite a similar topics have been discussed on serverfault for a few times already. As far as I remember, the last one was [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003264/aggregated-logs-from-microservices-into-single-web-interface/1003748#1003748).

There multiple logging solutions for k8s. You shall be able to find the one that fits your environment.